# $F(x,y) = ( \frac x { ( x^2 + y^2 ) ^ n } , \frac y { ( x^2 + y^2 ) ^ n } )$ ; is there a potential from which $F$ derivate?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

let $$F(x,y) = ( \frac x { ( x^2 + y^2 ) ^ n } ,  \frac y { ( x^2 + y^2 ) ^ n } )$$

I'm searching where this function is defined, and then for which $ n \in \mathbb R $ there exists (or doesn't) a potentiel from which $F$ derivate.

---

So far, I have found that for any $ n \in \mathbb N^* $, $ D_f = \Omega = \mathbb R^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}  $ ; and for any $n \leq 0$,  $ \Omega = \mathbb R^2$

For the second part of the question, I guess that for $ n > 1  $ and $ n \leq 0 $ , there will be a potential. But I don't know if my guess is true, and maybe there is an easy way to prove it.

The only method I know is to find a potential and then to prove that its derivative is $F$.

My problem is that when the domain is not simply connected, I can't use the method of computing the curl and seeing if it's equal to zero, which is a necessary condition for $F$ beeing the derivative of a potential.

Because, when $ n \leq 0 $, we have that the domain is simply connected, and :

$ curl F =  0 $ ; so we know that we can find a potential. But in the other cases, how to do this?

---

I'm sorry if this exercice is really basic... I'm learning and searching for an efficient method :)

Comment: Hint:  Try to guess a function $\phi_n(x,y)$ such that $\mathrm{grad}\phi_n=F_n$.  I bet you can guess it if you try three or four times.  Once you've guessed the answer, you will be able to tell which values for $n$ work.  The proof is merely differentiating the correct $\phi$ and verifying that the result is F.  The domain does not need to be simply connected for the proof to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\not=1$, let $G(x,y)=\frac1{2(-n+1)}(x^2+y^2)^{-n+1}$, (on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0,0\}$ for $n\gt1$).

For $n=1$, let $G(x,y)=\frac12\cdot \ln (x^2+y^2)$, (again exclude the origin).